# South Africa passport traveling from France to New Zealand

Tags: uk, transit-visas, south-african-citizens

Living in France. Traveling to New Zealand via UK. I have valid Schengen Visa and New Zealand Visa do i need a Visa to transit through the airport in Heathrow?